# Having 'this' as second parameter in foreach iterator for QList derived class

Tags: c++, qt, foreach

First I want to make it clear that this is a homework based question. That being the case, I want to 'understand' where my thinking is going haywire and not just have an answer given ;)

I have a class called RegistrationList that is derived from QList like such:

```
class RegistrationList : public QList<Registration *>
```

The Registration object has two children classes so the list RegistrationList have pointers to objects of the original Registration class as well as its two children:

```
class GuestRegistration : public Registration
```

and

```
class StudentRegistration : public Registration
```

the class RegistrationList must have a function prototyped like this:

```
 void displayList();
```

What this function needs to do is call a function called

```
QString toString();
```

in all the objects in the list.

Now this is what I have for the implementation of the

```
 void displayList();
```

member function of RegistrationList class:

```
void RegistrationList::displayList()
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    cout << "\nHere follows a list of all registrations:";
    cout << "\n=========================================\n";

    foreach(Registration *r, this) { r->toString(); }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like it at all. The way I see this is that I want to iterate over a list containing a collection of Registration like objects. Each of these objects have a member function called

```
toString();
```

to print out pretty formatted info. This works 100%. If I comment out the foreach line the code compiles with no issues. The only thing I can think of is that foreach doesn't like to have

```
this
```

as its second parameter.

It is not a must that I have to use foreach but it will bug me to no end if I cannot find out why it doesn't work although it 'seems' as if it should...

Comment: General note: There's no point in inheriting from a container like QList. It has no virtual methods one can reimplement. Better follow the "Composition over Inheritance" rule and make the QList a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foreach requires the second argument to be a reference to an object. You therefore need to dereference this:

```
foreach(Registration *r, *this) { r->toString(); }
```

You also probably want to write r->toString(); to the stream you have just created.

Comment: fontanini, thanks so much! I changed it to 'foreach(Registration *r, *this) { cout << r->toString(); }'

Comment: Did it work? I've never used foreach, but that looked like it could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are implementing the class incorrectly (unless you were given this explicitly).  I'm thinking the QList is supposed to be a member of the class RegistrationList and not the super class for the RegistrationList class.

That said, to use the foreach it would look like this:

```
foreach(Registration * r, RegList) { r->toString(); } //Where RegList is the QList member of RegistrationList
```

Comment: The way the UML diagram was given has a arrow with a blank arrow head pointing away from the RegistrationList class towards the QList<Registration *> class. That means RegistrationList is the parent right? But thinking about it now, it actually makes a lot more sense to have a QList member. I just double checked and the UML diagram doesn't have any members, only functions. Thanks for the help and info :)